# WiFi network suddenly disabled

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, adapter

First time poster in this community and a relatively new Linux user (i.e. high-level explanations are super helpful).

System and Hardware

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- WiFi Card: Intel Wireless-AC 9260
- Logical Name: wlp2s0

So, I know this WiFi card works because, well, it was working previously with no issues. Then it just stopped connecting. I used `lshw` to verify that the network adapter is disabled.

I used `ip link set dev wlp2s0 up` and verified that it's up using `ip link show`. But the network adapter is still disabled. So I guess my question, where do I go from here?

Comment: Try `rfkill list`. Do you have a laptop with a hardware switch or Fn key to disable/enable WiFi?

Comment: `rfkill list` returns two things: `phy0: Wireless LAN` and `hci0 Bluetooth`. Neither are soft or hard blocked.

I don't have an Fn key or hardware switch, unfortunately.